# How would be the best way to render a camera oscura

Tags: rendering

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura

I am trying to recreate a pinhole light effect in Blender. I tried in Luxcore but with my settings it gets very slow and the results are very poor. I am working with low realism. I am really more interested in the silhouettes of objects and the shadows that they cast. I am looking to recreate some curious effects I have observed of the shadows cast when sunlight shines through dense foliage.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://youtu.be/B98Mu_35NFM) seems to be the best description that deals with both EEVEE and Cycles

Answer (score 2):

These steps are from [This tutorial](https://youtu.be/B98Mu_35NFM).

- Delete everything from the scene but the default cube.
- Edit the default cube
- Select all
- Edge -> subdivide so that you now have edge loops everywhere.
- Select the center vertex of one of the faces and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel it.
- Set the bevel *Segments* to 3
- Set the bevel *Shape* to 0.085
- Set the bevel *Width* small. I used 0.034m

[image: Bevel settings]

- delete the resulting faces, giving a circular hole in the center of one face.

[image: box with hole]

- add a new material
- Make it black
- set its roughness and specularity to 0
- assign it to every face except the four faces *opposite* the hole.

[image: material for the body]

If you're using EEVEE as your render engine, disable soft shadows.

Make sure that the world generates no light.

To demonstrate place a point lamp at (2,0,0) and gave it 1000w of power.  Place the camera at the hole and pointed it at the back wall. Give it a 17mm focal length:

[image: Side view showing camera and point lamp placement.]

Here's what the back wall render looks like in *Cycles*:

[image: cycles render view]

Comment: Thank you Marty for answering this question. You have described how to make a basic pinhole camera although the surface on which the image falls should not be matte black.

Comment: I need some help with the render settings, I am not looking for anything near photo-realism but I do need to render considerably more detail than just a point source.

Comment: Take a look at [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/0LhwATTBfLA) by MrSorbias for how he approaches the lighting.

Comment: I will still need a much higher sensitivity, I will need to be able to render several objects in a 3d space, I could work without indirect light at a pinch. The objects could have emit materials. The light would have to pass through several different shaped orifices in the camera obscura the result would a compound image. I will then need about 250 frames of animation for each test. I will need dozens of tests.